# Transform coordinates EPSG:32628 to EPSG:3857 Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, openlayers, coordinates

I need to transform the example coordinates to a different projection in Openlayers3, the EPSG:32628 to EPSG:3857. I made a function to do it but the result is exactly the same numbers.

```
function plsHelp(){
    var pt = [459123.1209, 3108334.7701];
    var scr = new ol.proj.Projection('EPSG:32628');
    var dest = new ol.proj.Projection('EPSG:3857');
    var test= ol.proj.transform(pt,scr,dest);
    console.log(test);
}
```

What is wrong with the function that is preventing the tranformation of the coordinates from EPSG:32628 to EPSG:3857 in Openlayers 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenLayers natively includes the two following projections only: `EPSG:3857` and `EPSG:4326`.  To be able to transform to or from any other projections, you must use the **Proj4JS** library.

Try adding the two following scripts, the first being the Proj4JS library itself, the other the definition of the `EPSG:32628` projection:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.3/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="http://epsg.io/32628.js"></script>
```

Comment: After adding the scripts and removing the src and dest variables worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the projection view only, you could define it right at beginning when you initiate the ol.view. code like:

```
   var view = new ol.View({
      //change projection to WGS84 
      projection: "EPSG:4326",
      center: [-98.5284468774974,50.71391708013823],
            zoom: 8
    });
```

If you'd like to do a actual conversion, you could use **openlayer's ol.proj.transform**, from [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.transformExtent). Code like below:

```
var oldCode = OSM_layer.getSource().getProjection().getCode(); // Getting projection of target layer 
newCoord = ol.proj.transformExtent([extent.j[0], extent.j[1], extent.j[2], extent.j[3]], oldCode, 'EPSG:4326'); // perform projection transform with given extent.
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! All over the internet, and this answer helped me get what I wanted over the line. Specifically this to get the current views extent after projection transform: `const extent = view.calculateExtent(map.getSize()); const bboxCoords = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');`